# Problema com AJAX JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Código no index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function carregaPagina(item, pai, filho, url) {
                var caminho = item != null ? $(item).attr('data-click') : url;
                if (item != null) {
                    if ($(item).attr('data-json') != null) {
                        $('#' + $(item).attr('local-json')).html($(item).attr('data-json'));
                    }
                }
                if (pai != "" && pai != null) {
                    $('#' + pai).slideToggle(1000);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: caminho,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#' + filho).slideToggle(0);
                        $('#' + filho).html(data);
                        $('#' + filho).slideToggle(1000, function () {
                            if (typeof completaLoad !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(completaLoad)) {
                                completaLoad();
                            }

                            if ($('#' + pai).css('display') !== 'none') {
                                $('#' + pai).slideToggle(0);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('click', '.grid', function (e) {
                    if (e.handled !== true) {
                        carregaPagina(this, 'TelaConsulta', 'TelaEditar', null);
                        e.handled = true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .grid, .item, .btnVoltar {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            #TelaConsulta {
                background-color: #81BEF7;
            }
            #TelaEditar {
                background-color: #58FAAC;
            }
            #TelaItem {
                background-color: #F6D8CE;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="TelaConsulta">
            <ul>
                <li><span class="grid" data-click="editar.php?id=25">Editar</span></li>
                <li><span class="grid" data-click="editar.php?id=35">Editar</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="TelaEditar">
        </div>
        <div id="TelaItem">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código no editar.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.item', function (e) {
            if (e.handled !== true) {
                debugger;
                var url = 'item.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>';
                carregaPagina(null, 'TelaEditar', 'TelaItem', url);
                e.handled = true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        $('#TelaEditar .btnVoltar').click(function () {
            $('#TelaEditar').slideToggle(1000, function () {
                $('#TelaConsulta').slideToggle(1000);
                $('#TelaEditar').empty();
                $('#TelaEditar').removeAttr('style');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
Código: <?php
    echo $_GET['id'];
?><br><br>
<span class="item">Item</span><br><br>
<span class="btnVoltar">Voltar</span>
```

Código no item.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#TelaItem .btnVoltar').click(function () {
            $('#TelaItem').slideToggle(1000, function () {
                $('#TelaEditar').slideToggle(1000);
                $('#TelaItem').empty();
                $('#TelaItem').removeAttr('style');
            });
            return false;
        });
        debugger;
    });
</script>
Código: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?><br><br>
<span class="btnVoltar">Voltar</span>
```

No arquivo index.php clique no 1º Editar.

Na tela de editar ele mostra o Id 25, inseri um debugger no botão Item do arquivo editar.php note que quando você clica no botão ele abre a VM108.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inseri um debugger no arquivo item.php note que ele abre o VM119 e retornar Id 25.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida clique no botão voltar do arquivo item.php e em seguida clique no botão de voltar do editar.php.
No arquivo index.php clique no 2º Editar, ao exibir o arquivo editar.php ele retorna Id 35.

Quando você clica no botão Item no arquivo editar.php note que ele reabre o VM108.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando é exibido o conteúdo do item.php note ele que abre o VM141 e retornar Id 25.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a minha dúvida, somente na 1ª vez ele retorna o Id correto, em todas as outras tentativas ele retorna o Id do 1º acesso.

Link simulação: [link](http://microworks.com.br/cristiano/teste/)

Comment: Publique a instrução do evento clique que você faz para chamar essa função.

Comment: Faz um JsFiddle e simule a dificuldade, pois ainda está confuso de entender.

Comment: Melhorei o texto para explicar a situação

Comment: Eu não consegui encontrar onde você chama esse método carregaPagina() passando os parametros a ele.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo e a função que chama o carregaPagina()

Comment: Amigo, seu código está um pouco problematico. Você está usando onclick() na tag, mas ao mesmo tempo usa JQuery(). Vou postar a possível solução.

Comment: Qual é o retorno do carregaPagina? Você não está limpando o evento de click ao carregar uma nova página, o evento continuará o mesmo enquanto você não limpar o evento. Pelo que imagino esse carregaPagina está vindo um JS junto que você quer usar no lugar do antigo, certo?

Comment: carregaPagina está retornando HTML e JS. Exatamente, até coloquei o nocache na página, mas não tive sucesso. Como deveria proceder para limpar o evento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queria primeiramente agradecer ao colega @GabrielKatakura que me deu a ideia do que poderia ser, o problema está ocorrendo pois o evento de click continuava ativo.

Como estou carregando através de Ajax código HTML e JS não sabia que ao criar um evento de click o mesmo ficaria ativo, na tela que estou carregando estou usando a chamada `$(document).on()`, ao retornar para tela inicial não estou removendo o evento ao qual deveria usar a chama `$(document).off()`.

Meu arquivo editar.php ficou assim:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.item', function (e) {
            if (e.handled !== true) {
                debugger;
                var url = 'item.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>';
                carregaPagina(null, 'TelaEditar', 'TelaItem', url);
                e.handled = true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        $('#TelaEditar .btnVoltar').click(function () {
            $('#TelaEditar').slideToggle(1000, function () {
                //Removendo evento de click
                $(document).off('click', '.item');
                $('#TelaConsulta').slideToggle(1000);
                $('#TelaEditar').empty();
                $('#TelaEditar').removeAttr('style');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
Código: <?php
    echo $_GET['id'];
?><br><br>
<span class="item">Item</span><br><br>
<span class="btnVoltar">Voltar</span>
```

Esta situação ocorre pois estou passando o Id diretamente no JS, se por ventura eu buscasse o valor em um campo de formulário por exemplo, não haveria a necessidade de limpar o evento.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, no evento onclick() que você sua na tag `<a>`, você passa 4 parametros, mas no método checkData(), você não passa nenhum.

Tente isto:

```
function checkData(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 ) {

    var link = "/Login/Validar";

    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data == null || data.Sucesso == false) {
            mostraModalLogin();
        } else {
            switch ( arg1 ) {
                case "carregaPagina":
                    carregaPagina(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
                    break;
            }
        }
    })
    .fail(function () {
        mostraModalEvento('LoginFalhaLogin', '0', null, false);
    });

    return false;
}
```

Para melhorar seu código, eu usaria um evento `$( selector ).click()`, ao invés de usar um onclick() inline na tag.

Comment: E aquela variável arg, tá ali só de enfeite?

Comment: @GabrielKatakura, poderia me dizer qual o escopo da variavel arguments ? -Não vi sua declaração no código dele, e onde é especificado que ela recebe os parametros na chamada ao onclick() ?

Comment: Pessoal a minha função checkData está ok, meu problema está no fato que depois que carrego a tela de edição e retorno para tela de consulta, eu seleciono outro item e quando clico no botão da cadastrar ele chama a mesma VM, ou seja, ele está passando o mesmo Id da primeira vez que acessei. Se eu clicar em inspecionar no meu fonte está tudo ok, só que por algum motivo o navegador se perde e cai sempre no debugger daquela VM do print.

Comment: Você testou o que publiquei ou nem se deu ao trabalho ?

Comment: @Duque Sim testei a sua recomendação, mas o problema persiste, parece que ele fica em cache e só tem acesso a esta VM.

Comment: Se você montar um Fiddle com o exemplo, eu analisarei melhor e com certeza vamos encontrar a solução.

Comment: @Duque arguments é uma variável disponível para toda função, o escopo dela naquele caso é exatamente a função checkData. E ela não precisa receber os parâmetros de checkData, arguments é justamente um objeto que representa os argumentos de uma função, e antes de sair falando algo como "Você testou o que publiquei ou nem se deu ao trabalho?", tenha mais certeza do que está falando, porque sua solução é absolutamente inútil. Fica link para fins didáticos:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: @Duque consegui separar do projeto a parte que está com problema, atualizei no corpo da pergunta. Adicionei um link para que seja possível visualizar o código fonte.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura o código postado por mim é como eu disse "possível solução", não afirmei em hipotese alguma que iria solucionar já que o problema está dificil de compreender.

Comment: @CristianoÁvilaSalomão gostaria de algo prático, por exemplo um Fiddle do projeto, porque desta forma, fica dificil de testar. Creia que isso não é um problema de Cache.

Comment: index.html
https://jsbin.com/gamevo/edit?html,console,output

editar.html
https://jsbin.com/xosava/edit?html,js,output

item.html
https://jsbin.com/xosava/1/edit?html,js,output